# Nested async/await with Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

If I have the following functions where `funcC` calls `funcA` and `funcB` which both make requests to a website.

Will promise.all work as intended to make the functions execute concurrently or will funcA/B block at their respective await calls?

```
const funcA = async () => {
    const url = 'https://example.com'
    const method = 'GET'
    const credentials = 'include'
    const mode = 'cors'
    const response = await fetch(url, { method, mode, credentials })
    const cookie = response.headers.get('set-cookie')
    return cookie.split('=')[1].split(';')[0]
}
```

.

```
const funcB = async () => {
    const url = 'https://example.net'
    const method = 'GET'
    const mode = 'no-cors'
    await fetch(url, { method, mode }) // return not used
}
```

.

```
const funcC = async () => {
    let promises = []
    promises.push(funcA())
    promises.push(funcB())
    promises = await Promise.all(promises);
    // do something with promises
}
```

Comment: *Will promise.all work as intended to make the functions execute concurrently* Yes, nothing in there blocks

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!